# Solve the mixed value problem for $1$-D wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, wave-equation, laplacian

Solve the mixed value problem for $1$-D wave equation
\begin{align*}
u_{tt}  & =u_{xx}\text{, }x>0\text{, }t>0,\\
u(x,0)    & =g(x), u_t(x,0)
=0,\,x>0,\\
u_t(0,t)    & =\alpha u_x(0,t)  ,~t>0,
\end{align*}
where $\alpha\ne-1$ is a constant and $g\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^{+})  $ vanishes near $x=0$.

I can get the fundamental solution for homogeneous and non-homogeneous but I am unable to solve this mixed value problem. Please help.

Comment: Are you familiar with d'Alembert's solution?

Comment: Yes, I am. I am unable to do the mixed one.